# Pivot column to row in mysql result output

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following result

```
A   B   C
1   2   3
```

How do I get the result like

```
title1  title2
A   1
B   2
C   3
```

My query is something like this

```
select
sum(if(d =4,1,0)) AS 'A',
sum(if(d = 4 and (datediff(curdate(), r_date)=1),1,0)) AS ' B',
sum(if(d = 1 and (datediff(curdate(), r_date)=2),1,0)) AS ' C'
from delay ;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your actual data set, or does it really consist of just one record?

Comment: My table has multiple fields, A,B,C are the names of the output I want,

Comment: when i run my query my result appear like the first one, I want it rotated or transposed to help with downloading in that format to excel, to avoid transposing in excel.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to unpivot a table in MySQL.  One way to do this would be to use a series of unions:

```
SELECT 'A' AS title1, A AS title2
FROM delay
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' AS title1, B AS title2
FROM delay
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' AS title1, C AS title2
FROM delay
```